# Run Laravel cron job in a background - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, cron

I have a cron job with Laravel:

```
    public function handle(){
    $reimport = $this->argument('reimport');

    $lib = new CustomLibrary();

    $lib->importAll();

}
```

I am calling this in my controller:

```
Artisan::call('my_command');
```

or in `SSH`:

```
php artisan my_command
```

Te problem is that in both places the job is not in a background, because it takes more than minute to finish.

Is there way to make that job to run in a background in the controller and in `SSH` (optional) ?

Comment: You'd have to use a queue. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues

Comment: Yes, but is there a way without a Laravel queues ?

Comment: You could look into `pcntl_fork()` - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php - but this would only work on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

To start the Laravel Scheduler itself, we only need to add one Cron job which executes every minute. Go to your terminal, ssh into your server, cd into your project and run this command.

```
crontab -e
```

This will open the server Crontab file, paste the code below into the file, save and then exit.

```
* * * * * php /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Do not forget to replace /path/to/artisan with the full path to the Artisan command of your Laravel Application.